# Trouble accessing the property of a class in Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

In `index.cshtml` I am using Ajax. In click event of `.removelink` to get changes from action controller as follows:

```
 $(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
                    // Get the id from the link
                    var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
                    if (recordToDelete != '' || recordToDelete != null) {
                        // Perform the ajax post                             
                    $.ajax({
                            //contentType: 'application/json',
                            //dataType: 'text',
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            url: '/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/',
                            data: { id: recordToDelete },
                            success: function (data) {  
                                if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                                    $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                                }
                                else {
                                    $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                                }
                                $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                                $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                                $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
                            }
                        });                   
                    }               
                });
```

And in controller:

```
//AJAX: /ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/5
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            //Remove the item from the cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
            //string albumName = _context.Carts
            //.Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Album.Title;
            Cart cartt = ShoppingCart.getCartForGetalbumName(id);
            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);
            // Display the confirmation message
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message = HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(cartt.Album.Title) +
            " has been removed from your shopping cart.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                //CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };
            return Json(results);     
        }
```

However, it does not work. Additionally, the text of the tags does not change and `fadeOut()` does not work.

When I send a unit field (eg, a string or an integer) Jason reads it well.
However, when I send a class containing some properties (like the example above), its value in the data parameter is problematic.

Comment: When I send a unit field (eg, a string or an integer) Jason reads it well.
But when I send a class containing some properties (like the example above), its value in the data parameter is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add The following code to convert data to json in RemoveFromCart controller action:

```
var resulTtoJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);
```

and return json type :

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult RemoveFromCart(int id)
        {
            //Remove the item from the cart
            var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
            // Get the name of the album to display confirmation
            //string albumName = _context.Carts
            //.Single(item => item.RecordId == id).Album.Title;
            Cart cartt = ShoppingCart.getCartForGetalbumName(id);
            // Remove from cart
            int itemCount = cart.RemoveFromCart(id);
            // Display the confirmation message
            var results = new ShoppingCartRemoveViewModel
            {
                Message ="محصول"+ cartt.Album.Title +
            "از سبد خریدتان حذف گردید.",
                CartTotal = cart.GetTotal(),
                //CartCount = cart.GetCount(),
                ItemCount = itemCount,
                DeleteId = id
            };

            var resulTtoJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(results);

            return Json(resulTtoJson);
```

also add the following code in view to convert data to javascript type:

```
var data =JSON.parse(dataa);
```

and use it:

```
$(".RemoveLink").click(function () {
                // Get the id from the link
                var recordToDelete = $(this).attr("data-id");
               // alert(recordToDelete);
                if (recordToDelete != '' || recordToDelete != null) {
                    // Perform the ajax post
                    $.post("/ShoppingCart/RemoveFromCart/", { id: recordToDelete},
                        function (dataa) {
                            // Successful requests get here
                            // Update the page elements
                                 var data =JSON.parse(dataa);

                            if (data.ItemCount == 0) {
                                $('#row-' + data.DeleteId).fadeOut('slow');
                            } else {
                                $('#item-count-' + data.DeleteId).text(data.ItemCount);
                            }
                            $('#cart-total').text(data.CartTotal);
                            $('#update-message').text(data.Message);
                            $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.CartCount + ')');
}
                        });       

                }               
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your property to lowercase , try to use :

```
success: function (data) 
{  
    if (data.itemCount == 0) {
        $('#row-' + data.deleteId).fadeOut('slow');
    }
    else {
        $('#item-count-' + data.deleteId).text(data.itemCount);
    }
    $('#cart-total').text(data.cartTotal);
    $('#update-message').text(data.message);
    $('#cart-status').text('Cart (' + data.cartCount + ')');
}
```